# Sensor Tag CC2650 - reading movement sensor

Tags: sensors, texas-instruments

Is there any way to read data continuously upon request without using notifications? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have notifying and reading mechanism of data transfer - in CC2650 almost all characteristics support both mechanism of data transfer.  But other characteristics can only be accessed based only one method of data reading. One such example is the reading of the buttons states on the CC2650STK and CC2541DK that can only be read by means of the notification mechanism. But, notifications is preferred if you need a higher data transfer rate between the SensorTag and your application.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an app capable of working with all the sensors from CC2541DK, CC2650STK, ThunderBoard React and Sense (e.g. accelerometer., magnetometer, gyroscope etc.), you can download it from: [BLE SensorTags (blessTags)](http://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9p054xsjjr1n) – the software is able of giving new uses (movement & magnetic security, accelerometer mouse, PC remote control and wireless presenters) to all these IoT SensorTags. For more info: [Bluetooth low energy SensorTag](http://www.blesstags.eu).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It looks like you're linking to your own site in your answers (blesstags.eu). When doing so, you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your answers. For more information, see the [help center](/help/promotion).